# FileUriExposedException in Oreo

Tags: android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo, android-fileprovider

I am trying to share a text file. I have followed all required step to share file using FileProvider for >=Nougat but Still getting FileUriExposedException :

```
Fatal Exception: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/abc.txt exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
       at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1975)
       at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2363)
       at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:941)
       at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9944)
       at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9950)
       at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9929)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1622)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4751)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4691)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5112)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5080)
       at com.abc.sendChatThroughEmail(ConversationActivity.java:841)
       at com.abc.onOptionsItemSelected(ConversationActivity.java:752)
       at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3696)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:679)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
       at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:321)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1217)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3203)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4151)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

**My code for sharing is :**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N || Config.ONLY_INTERNAL_STORAGE) {
            try {
                String packageId = context.getPackageName();
                return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, packageId + FILE_PROVIDER, file);
            } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    throw new SecurityException();
                } else {
                    return Uri.fromFile(file);
                }
            }
        } else {
            return Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
```

and Also added permission to intent as:

**intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);**

If anyone can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

**Edit:**
My code for making intent is folowing:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/html");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "abc");
        try {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileBackend.getUriForFile(activity, chatFile));
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.no_permission_to_access_x, chatFile.getAbsolutePath()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/5906447

Comment: I have reffered this before. As I said in question I have followed fileProvider approach for Nougat and above.. Still facing error

Answer (score 1):

You do not need this check (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) .

It is the Target Version that needs to be API 24 or above not the build or android version. 
You are getting this exception because the uri being generated is still file://.

Comment: I think the check doesn't effect the outcome as the exception occured on Oreo. Which should be using fileProvider uri.

Comment: `/**
     * If this is a {@code file://} Uri, it will be reported to`
     `* {@link StrictMode}.
     *
     * @hide
     */`
    `public void checkFileUriExposed(String location) {
        if ("file".equals(getScheme())
                && (getPath() != null) && !getPath().startsWith("/system/")) {
            StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(this, location);
        }
    }`



 This is where the uri check fails.  Can you log/debug the uri you are generating ? @SohailKhan